# Good way to keep PHPBB3 boards secure from hackers?

Tags: php, security, phpbb3

Keep hearing of other forums getting hacked.  I realise that if a hacker is that determined, they will find a way, but what are the actions that you can take to try to ensure, wherever possible, that it doesn't happen please ?

Answer (score 5):

There will be another vulnerability in PHPBB3,  and you will be hacked.  Try and keep PHPBB3 up to date.  I know for a fact that [Simple Machines Forums](http://www.simplemachines.org/) is a lot more secure because I have manually audited both of them.

1)Without a doubt the most important thing you can do to make any web application more secure is to use a web application firewall such as [Mod_Security](http://www.modsecurity.org/).

2)Make sure you are using a modern linux distribution that is using ether SELinux or AppArmor,  SELinux is more secure. **DO NOT USE WINDOWS.**

3)Make sure your mysql user account only has access to the PHPBB3 database,  and **NOTHING ELSE**.  Most importantly make sure PHPBB3's account cannot access the mysql.user table!  "File privileges" is by far the worst thing you can give a web application.  File privileges is **much** worse than "grant" because an attacker will try to inject sql like this: `' union select '<?php eval($_GET[e])?>' into outfile "/var/www/backdoor.php"--` to upload his backdoor,  "grant"  can only be used if the attacker can "stack" queries and mysql_query() does not allow this and there for cannot be used in a sql injection attack.

4)Firewall off port 3306,  or whatever port mysql is using.  You should only allow ports that you absolutely need, and be extra careful with your database.

5)Run [PHPSecInfo](http://phpsec.org/projects/phpsecinfo/) and make sure that that it doesn't throw "Red" warnings.

6)Run [OpenVAS](http://www.openvas.org/) against your server,  this is probably the first thing a hacker will do.

Answer (score 2):

You can never say how to be 100% safe from hackers, but you can at least follow some security policies to minimalize the risk.

- Use strong root password,
- track critical issues on net and fix them asap,
- use captcha for continuous logins,
- use e-mail confimation for new registrations,
- disable HTML in posts and signatures.

Comment: It is very clear that you have never hacked a web application.